# How to convert a long value into DateTime format dd:mm:yyy hh:mm:ss in Groovy

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, groovy

How can i convert a long value to DateTime in groovy.

The thins i tried.

```
def time= new Long(LastModifiedDate + timeLeft)
def time_main= time/ 1000;  where time is a long value
            def time:final= time+ 3600 + time_main;
            LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(Finish2, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
            String formattedDate = dateTime.format(formatter);
            test.setFinishingTime(formattedDate);
```

laster I am writing into SQl table having datetime2(0) format using **setFinishingTime**. I get the conversion error. please help.

For reference the **setFinishingTime** is declare as:

```
public Date getFinishingTime()
    {
        return getPropertyContainer().getDate(FINISHING_TIME, -1)
    }

    public void setFinishingTime(Date finishingTime)
    {
        getPropertyContainer().setDate(FINISHING_TIME, finishingTime)
    }
```

and **FINISHING_TIME** is declared as in other class:

```
public static final Date FINISHING_TIME = "FinishingTime"
```

How can i convert long into Date/DateTime format suitable for SQL table. Thank you.

Comment: share what inside the long value. if  milliseconds since the 1970 then `new Date(milliseconds)` should help.

Comment: @daggett : The value is 1550827819701

Comment: use `new Date(1550827819701)`

Comment: @daggett : You mean, Date d = new Date(time);
   test.setFinishingTime(d);  with respect to my above code.

Comment: `setFinishingTime` accepts `Date` as input, so you need to convert long in milliseconds to a Date. `setFinishingTime( new Date(1550827819701) )` should work. to make formatted date (string) use this code: `new Date(1550827819701).format('dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: Yes i did in above, But when i use string or even just taking a date and using in my groovy setter i get the erro when i debug **Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError**

Comment: what kind of `Date` are you using? `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date` ? or maybe some other? and provide the cause of the error...

Comment: I am using java.util.Date. I am just confused that i see lot of long value to datetime conversion, all are in string. But what should i do if i have a Sql table with a column in Datetime2  format. This string datetime what i got, i cannot insert there because of string to date time conversion. How do i do that. ?

Comment: i think it's another question because context required on that.

Comment: Its the same question. I just provided with the codes. Eventhough it an another question, do you have an idea to implement it ?

Comment: if you are using groovy.sql.Sql: then this kind of command should work: `sql.executeUpdate "insert into delme values( ${125} , ${ new java.sql.Timestamp(1550827830701) } )"`

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your above code.